# Bootstrap button shifted to the right outside containing div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've got a very simple bootstrap page that has a div with a column of buttons in it. For no apparent reason the buttons are shifted slightly to the right:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The containing div (as highlighted above) has no padding or margin:

[image]

and the buttons have the same margin applied on both sides:

[image]

associated html:

```
<div class="cinema-list" style="max-width: 700px;" class="m-auto">
    <h2>Select Cinema</h2>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cinemaSearchInput">Search</label>
        <input 
            type="text" 
            class="form-control" 
            id="cinemaSearchInput" 
            placeholder="Cinema name..."
            [(ngModel)]="searchString"
            >
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="cinemaList != null">

        <button 
            *ngFor="let cinema of cinemaList" 
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary cinema-button m-1 w-100"
            (click)="selectCinema(cinema)"
            >
            <span>{{cinema.name}}</span>
            <i 
                *ngIf="isFavoriteCinema(cinema)"
                class="fa fa-heart pl-1 heart" 
                aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>

    </div>

    <div 
        *ngIf="cinemaList == null" 
        class="d-flex align-items-center pt-2">
            <span class="spinner-border text-primary mr-2"></span>
            <span>Loading...</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and scss:

```
.cinema-list{
    .cinema-button{
        display: block;
    }

    .cinema:hover{
        background-color: $primary;
    }
}
```

I can't see any reason why the buttons are shifted. Is this a bug with bootstrap?

This is boostrap 4.3.1

Thanks

Comment: The CSS box-sizing property allows us to include the padding and border in an element's total width and height. => style="max-width: 700px;" => count max widht of yours elements and it is 708px , 8 px diff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you added class `m-1` in the button. please remove that class from it.

Replace

```
 class="btn btn-primary cinema-button m-1 w-100"
```

With

```
 class="btn btn-primary cinema-button w-100"
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: That fixes it. Thanks very much. Makes sense as well. Before I applied the btn-block I needed the margin for vertical space.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `my-1` and `mx-0` class instead of `m-1` class.

```
        <button 
            *ngFor="let cinema of cinemaList" 
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary cinema-button my-1 mx-0 w-100"
            (click)="selectCinema(cinema)"
            >
            <span>{{cinema.name}}</span>
            <i 
                *ngIf="isFavoriteCinema(cinema)"
                class="fa fa-heart pl-1 heart" 
                aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alok Mali's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58498216/1188322) fixes the issue.

> I can't see any reason why the buttons are shifted. Is this a bug with bootstrap?

No, this is how CSS is designed.

**This is the root cause why this is happen.**

In Bootstrap by default all elements have `box-sizing:border-box;`

This is done by reset.scss

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box; // 1
}
```

For `border-box` the width and height properties of an element include the content, padding, and border, **but do not include the margin**. In your case you have a margin of `.25em` when you applied class `m-1`, thats why your element (button in this case) overlflowed.

More read of `box-sizing` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Hope this helps.